# for / since grammar to answer the how long ago question

Tags: grammar

can we use

> for since

to answer how long ago?
*how long ago did they study?
they studied *since* last 2 weeks
they studied *for*  2 weeks*

Answer (score 2):

***For*** and ***since*** both define periods of time (though they also have other uses). They do it in different ways.

*For* defines a period of time solely on its length.

> I've been waiting **for** two weeks!

*Since* defines it in relation to some particular event:

> I've been waiting **since** you called me.

The idea of an event can also include a particular point in time:

> They've been calling every day since two weeks ago.

However, that's usually more awkward than using *for*.

Now, *for* in itself doesn't position either the beginning or end of the period of time, just defines its length. Sometimes that's obvious, like if you use the past progressive. Sometimes it's not. If you want to be clear that it's that length of time up to now, you can use extra words:

> They've studies for **the last** two weeks.

Or of course to locate periods that aren't "up to now":

> I was there for two hours, starting around noon.

And of course, you can combine both:

> They had been there **for** two weeks, **since** they had arrived in the city.
>   I've been waiting **for** two weeks **since** you called!

Answer (score 0):

**We often use for and since when talking about time.**

**for** + period: a "period" is a duration of time - five minutes, two weeks, six years. For means "from the beginning of the period to the end of the period".

**since** + point: a "point" is a precise moment in time - 9 o'clock, 1st January, Monday. Since means "from a point in the past until now".

**For can be used with all tenses. Here are a few examples:**

> They study for two hours every day.
>
> They are studying for three hours today.
>
> He has lived in Bangkok for a long time.
>
> He has been living in Paris for three months.
>
> I worked at that bank for five years.
>
> Will the universe continue for ever?
>
> We do not use for with "all day", "all the time":
>
> I was there all day. (not for all day)

**Since is normally used with perfect tenses:**

> He has been here since 9am.
>
> He has been working since he arrived.
>
> I had lived in New York since my childhood.
>
> We also use since in the structure "It is [period] since":
>
> It was a year since I had seen her. How long is it since you got
>   married?